# Does the first-order energy correction in the degenerate case equals to the eigenvalues of the perturbation matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

According to Griffiths, the degenerate [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory) says that the first-order corrections to the energies are the eigenvalues of the perturbation matrix. Griffiths solves for the eigenvalues in the unperturbed energy eigenbasis. But, because the eigenvalues of a matrix are independent of the choice of basis, the eigenvalues are just the eigenvalues of the perturbation matrix $\delta H$ on any basis.

However, I encounter a problem where
$$
H_0=\frac{1}{4}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, \quad \text{and} \quad \delta H=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The eigenvalues of the perturbation matrix $\delta H$ equals to $-\frac{3}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, -\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}$. But the solution says the first order corrections to the energies are $-\frac{1}{4}, -\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}$. Why they are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant matrix that you need to diagonalize is not $\delta H$ itself, but its projection onto each one of the degenerate subspaces of $H_0$. Since the $E=1$ subspace is generated by $v_1=(1,0,0,0),v_2=(0,0,0,1)$ the matrix you need to diagonalize is then
$$\delta H_1 =\pmatrix{0 &\frac{1}{4}\\\frac{1}{4}&0}$$
(and similarly for $-1$) which will give the right corrections.